# Overflow error when mixing numpy arrays and regular python 2.7 arrays

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I'm having some trouble understanding the type conversions that occur when I try to put data from a numpy array into a regular python array.  I finally figured out enough to generate a minimal example that reproduces the error:

```
import numpy
import array

array_L = array.array('L', [0xFF000000]) 
numpy_L = numpy.array([1], dtype='L')

#this code raises and overflow
#OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
array_L[0] += numpy_L[0]
```

Why does the final line ever convert an intermediate value to C long?  Shouldn't it use C unsigned long?

From the [python array documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html), type `'L'` corresponds to an unsigned long of at least 32 bits.  The element in `numpy_L` array has type `numpy.uint32`.  I realize these are not exactly the same type, but I would have expected that they would be compatible.  If this addition is performed using unsigned long integers, there is no overflow.

If I perform the same calculation using only numpy arrays, or only standard library arrays, I have no issues.  However, the whole purpose of my code is to take a large numpy array and reformat it for use by a different object.

I can fix the problem by using an explicit cast to a python long integer, but it's slow.  My actual application has this inside 5 for loops with arrays of length 10,000 or so.

```
#works, but slow
array_L[0] += long(np_L[0])
```

Thanks!

Comment: try `array_L[0] += numpy_L.item(0)`, I think it's faster, but a for loop like this is generally slow.

Comment: That works, but I'm stumped as to why.  I hadn't made much use of `item()` before.  I didn't recognize the difference from `[]` and `__getitem__()`.  I'm still confused as to what is going on with the type conversions, but this is helpful.

Comment: `x[0]` returns a NumPy scalar value, `x.item(0)` returns a Python scalar value. Calculation with NumPy scalar value is slow.